# Помогите разобраться с импортом и экспортом js

Tags: javascript, функции, импорт, export

Ошибки:

- Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED.
- Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/.../js/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Почему возникают эти ошибки просто пытаюсь импортировать функцию. Что не так. Как правильно произвести импорт и экспорт. Просьба помочь..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import {double} from './alter.js';

console.log(double(5));
```

```
export function double(n) {
  return n * 2;
}
```

Comment: Ну на чистом английском же написано. Что бы работали модули нужен http-сервер.

Comment: В сообщении пишется что проблема не в импорте а CORS запретил выгружать. Ты не пробовал поставить плагин чтобы отключить CORD ?

Comment: @AlexeyTen тут проблема же не в сервере. Можно развернуть html, js без какого либо бекенда. По какой то причине не разрешена отдача js файла

Comment: @AndreyRF, из соображений конфиденциальности js в браузерной среде запрещено напрямую обращаться к другим файлам

Comment: А точно. Ну да нужен бэк получается. На ноде что нибудь можно.

Comment: @Andrey RF если это разместить в Github.io, создать репозиторий, а сами файлы оставить неизменными, это будет работать?

Comment: @Joji типа запускать это из репозитории GitHub ?

Comment: Короче @Joji  чтобы сайт работал, нужен веб сервер типа nginx или apach, они отдают всю статику сайта при запросе. Типа сперва выгружается html и дальше начинают подгружаться остальные файлы необходимые для работы страницы

Comment: @Andrey RF через github.io получилось, спасибо тебе.